# How to share/broadcast the screen of the iPad to a distant computer?

Tags: ipad, screen-sharing, handwriting

I want to write on my iPad and that a distant user (in a another city) can see (in live) what I write on my iPad. Is it possible?

I might use the app Nebo to write. So I was thinking: is it possible to broadcast the screen of my iPad? I am looking for an iOS only solution, but I can also connect the iPad to the mac...

Thanks.

Comment: Define _distant_. Down the hall? In another building? In another city? In another state/country?

Comment: In another city.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually Zoom Meeting lets you share your iPad's screen by using Airplay and a special plugin that you can install on your Mac computer to share its screen. Zoom even lets you focus all guests screens to see your iPad screen instead of whomever is speaking.

Here is their step-by-step guide to set that up.

https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201379235-Screen-Share-iPhone-iPad-Apps

Answer (score 4):

If you can use a computer what you can do is  connect the iPad to the computer through a USB cable then view the iPad screen using QuickTime. Then use screen sharing software so the person in the other place can view your computers which will have you iPads screen.

Comment: But, are there native solutions? That could capture directly the screen of the iPad?

Comment: @Colas there is no built in apps on the iPad that can stream

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no native iOS only solution for this. As stated [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5923571?tstart=0) and on other sites (with a little googling), OS X / MacOS does not act as an AirPlay receiver, only an AirPlay transmitter. For example, you can send your MacBook Pro screen somewhere, but your MacBook Pro cannot receive another screen.

You will either need **third-party software** like [AirServer](http://www.airserver.com/Mac) or [Unicorns](https://unicorns.io/info), an iOS app like [Livestream](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/livestream/id493086499?mt=8), or an AppleTV. The AppleTV might be the easiest because of its HDMI port and ability to work with any screen that has an HDMI port. All AirPlay options will be limited to the range of the WiFi network you are accessing -- if you get too much distance between the iPad and the computer, it won't work.

Your question isn't clear whether you want live viewing or not, so if it does not matter and you're running iOS 11, another option would be to make a screen recording.

Comment: Yes I want to live broadcast, to another city.

Answer (score 2):

I use teamviewer for giving tech support to my mother. They now have ios screen sharing, i have not tried it yet but i plan to.

[teamviewer ios screen sharing](https://www.teamviewer.us/features/ios-screen-sharing/)

Comment: as far as i know it teamviewers screensharing is just a remote screenshot where you as a supporter can say i wanna make a screenshot and the user on the otherside gets a dialogbox which asks him/her if he/she wanna send it to you. So it is not really screensharing.

Comment: As i said, i use it to give tech support to my mom, i can control her computer in Utah from Alaska as if it were right in front of me. From what i have read, the mobile version should be similar if not the same.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be TeamViewer app which available for iOS and Mac and Windows. You can share your screen as well as do voice and text chat within it. You can even give control to the remote user if you want. There is virtually no lag at all.

https://www.teamviewer.us/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see what each other are writing (and edit if you want as a bonus), you could check out [Google Docs](https://www.google.com.au/docs/about/). They let you see each other typing in real time and let the other person edit as well if you give them permission.