# Share iPad screen to Skype on MBA

Tags: ipad, screen-sharing, skype

I have a few collaborations that I work with and chat over Skype. Our conversations frequently involve discussions over calculations but with Skype I haven't been able to find a way to share my iPad screen and demonstrate some live work.

Is there any regular way or trick which would allow the Skype app on my MBA M1 (macOS 12.0.1) to share the iPad 6th gen (iPadOS 15.1) screen live?

One thing that succeeds is using an app like GoodNotes (which has app for both macOS and iPadOS) to sync your work and share it's screen on the MacBook during a Skype call and transfer that screen to iPad & use a stylus to write but the results are highly unsatisfactory.

Edit : Clarification

I cannot use another app besides Skype due to my collaborators being used to it and they won't install other apps like Zoom/Teamviewer. The method/trick has to involve either tricking Skype MacBook into allowing iPad screen sharing or using another app that allows for the iPad screen broadcast to Skype on MacBook.

Comment: Closely related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304447/how-to-share-broadcast-the-screen-of-the-ipad-to-a-distant-computer?rq=1

Comment: @nohillside My question is specifically for Skype - the task is very easy to achieve over Zoom / Google Meet etc.

Comment: Some answers there recommend Teamviewer.

Comment: @nohillside I guess I wasn't clear - I cannot use another app besides Skype due to my collaborators being used to it and they won't install other apps. Teamviewer can't help me. I'll update the question to reflect this.